# Data-binding Memory leakage issue in WPF UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I'm using the Data-binding int he following way with the **DependencyProperty** by it unable to release the memory when open the new form and when the same form is reopen the memory size taken by the form is increased.

The **.Xaml** file is as

```
<Border x:Name="brdMain" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=BorderColor}" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid x:Name="imgGrid">
            <Image x:Name="imgMain" Source="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImgMain}" Stretch="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImgStretch}"></Image>
            <InkCanvas EditingMode="Select" Background="#00000000" x:Name="inkCanvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=imgGrid}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=InkCanvasVisibility}">
                <Image Name="imgVirtualProp" Stretch="Fill" Width="150" Height="100" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
            </InkCanvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Image x:Name="imgShadow" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/PhotoBoothAgile;component/Images/Assets/Shadow.png" Width="{Binding ElementName=imgMain, Path=Width}"></Image>
        <Label x:Name="labelText" Content="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=LabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Wheat"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
```

The **.CS** file properties is as

```
public ImageWithCanvasUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource ImgMain
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Image.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImgMain", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageWithCanvasUC), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(ImageWithCanvasUC), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    //ImgStretch


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImgStreacthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImgStretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(ImageWithCanvasUC), new UIPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Fill));

    public Stretch ImgStretch
    {
        get { return (Stretch)GetValue(ImgStreacthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImgStreacthProperty, value); }
    }

    //InkCanvVisibility

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImgInkCanvasVisibiltyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InkCanvasVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ImageWithCanvasUC), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));

    public Visibility InkCanvasVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ImgInkCanvasVisibiltyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImgInkCanvasVisibiltyProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ImageWithCanvasUC), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.BurlyWood));

    private void UC_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgGrid.ClearValue(Grid.DataContextProperty);
        imgMain.ClearValue(Image.SourceProperty);
        imgMain.ClearValue(Image.StretchProperty);
        labelText.ClearValue(Label.ContentProperty);
        brdMain.ClearValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty);
        imgVirtualProp.ClearValue(Image.StretchProperty);
        imgVirtualProp.ClearValue(Image.SourceProperty);
        imgShadow.ClearValue(Image.SourceProperty);
        imgShadow.ClearValue(Image.StretchProperty);
        inkCanvas.ClearValue(InkCanvas.DataContextProperty);

        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(imgGrid);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(imgMain);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(labelText);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(imgVirtualProp);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(imgShadow);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(brdMain);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(inkCanvas);
    }
```

Comment: In .NET, memory is not freed immediately when objects are no longer referenced. The garbage collector usually frees unused memory at a later point in time. Therefore, your code in `UC_Unloaded` will not free the memory right away. For a test, call the garbage collector manually to see if there really is a memory leak.

Comment: by the **GC.Collect()** don't found any change in freeing the memory.

Comment: For testing, you should use `GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` ; otherwise, finalizers will not be called. If that doesn't change memory consumption: what data type of .NET objects are leaking? (You can tell that using a memory profiling tool, or using WinDbg).

Comment: @fmunkert the issue was resolve by **GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();** Thanks. but i don't understand why it is required to call the **GC.Collect** by force.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood me. Calling the GC is just for testing; you never should do that in the release version of your program. If the memory leak disappears by calling GC, then this means that there was no memory leak in the first place. Remember that .NET delays the freeing of memory until it is absolutely necessary; therefore, .NET programs often appear to have a larger memory consumption than comparable native programs. But as soon as the operating system requires more memory, the .NET GC will ensure that unused memory is freed.